# Incremental Mongodb Update

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to update my db incrementally by parsing a csv and counting how many times each person has been to a country or state, if they're within the US.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException  {          

    Scanner dir = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dir_loc;
    System.out.println("Enter File Directory:");
    dir_loc=dir.nextLine();

    Scanner dbloc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String db_loc;
    System.out.println("Enter Database location:");
    db_loc=dbloc.nextLine();

    Scanner port = new Scanner(System.in);
    int port_loc;
    System.out.println("Enter Port:");
    port_loc=port.nextInt();                

    dir.close();
    dbloc.close();
    port.close();

    System.out.println("uploading");        

    String directoryName = dir_loc; 
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();                

    DB dB = (new MongoClient(db_loc, port_loc)).getDB("visits"); 
    DBCollection dBCollection = dB.getCollection("Channel");
    BasicDBObject doc = null;
    for(File file: fileList) {      

        String dataFileName = file.toString();
        BufferedReader bReader = null;
        try {
            bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
        int statecount = 0;

        try {

            while((line = bReader.readLine()) !=null) {

                String dataValue[] = line.split("\t");                              
                String user_id = (dataValue[2]);
                String country = (dataValue[1]);                                            

                boolean user_idExists = dBCollection.equals(user_id);
                if(user_idExists){
                    if(dataValue[1].equals("US")) {
                        String state = (dataValue[5]);
                        System.out.println(state); 
                        boolean stateExists = dBCollection.equals(state);
                        if(stateExists){                                
                            statecount ++;
                            doc = new BasicDBObject("user_id", user_id).append("country", country).append("state", state)
                                    .append("count", statecount);                               
                        }
                        else{                               
                            statecount = 1;
                            doc = new BasicDBObject("user_id", user_id).append("country", country).append("state", state)
                                    .append("count", statecount);                               
                        }                           
                        }
                    else{
                        boolean countryExists = dBCollection.equals(country);
                        if(countryExists){
                            count ++;
                            doc = new BasicDBObject("user_id", user_id).append("country", country).append("count", count);
                        }
                        else{
                            count = 1;
                            doc = new BasicDBObject("user_id", user_id).append("country", country).append("count", count);
                        }
                    }
                }                       
                else {                      
                    count = 1;
                    doc = new BasicDBObject("user_id", user_id).append("country", country).append("count", count);                      
                }
            }                                               

            } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        try {

            bReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    dBCollection.insert(doc);
    System.out.println("upload complete");
}
```

}
The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b3421d"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "NY" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b3421e"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "NY" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b3421f"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "NY" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34220"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "JA" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34220"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "JA" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34221"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "SA" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34221"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "SA" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34221"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "SA" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34222"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "TX" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34223"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "TX" , "count" : 1}
```

but it should look like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b3421d"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "VN" , "state" : "NY" , "count" : 3}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34220"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "JA", "count" : 2}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34221"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "SA", "count" : 3}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53861247d121c16b38b34222"} , "user_id" : "5406" , "country" : "US" , "state" : "TX" , "count" : 2}
```

I'm not sure why I can't get state/country counts to increment?

Comment: Currently you insert every line into the database. In java you want to  iterate over your full csv file first keeping track of the information than at the end insert into the database. *OR* You could just insert everything into the database then use the database to do the counting using the aggregation framework

Comment: @KassymDorsel if I insert everything, won't the database be somewhat unsorted? I want to insert everything in a really clean way so it's optimized for querying, which is my motivation for doing the counting in java - but if there's a better way to do it, I'm all for it. I've updated my code to reflect moving the insert outside the loop

Comment: databases are not meant to be sorted. They are there to easily store and retrieve data in a defined structure. The structure is what is best based on the type of queries you will be running. If you are trying to track how many times a person went to said one way to do it is the following :: {id:1, travels:[{k:'US.CA', v:1}, {k:'',v:1},etc]} or {id:1, travels:[{country:'US', 'state:'CA', v:1}, etc]}. One document per person id with an array of all places they have been with count and add an index on 'k' or 'country' and 'state'

Comment: Also even by inserting into the database at the end won't make much difference since you create each object that you insert on each iteration. You would have to keep track of each user and their travel count in some sort of dictionary in java then after going thru all the rows in the csv you create the document and insert it